# Launch file with Electron app; get file's url (process variable)

Tags: node.js, electron, launch, electron-packager

I've packaged my electron app and I can double-click a file to have it launch the app.

However, I'm not being passed the url of the double-clicked file. It's not in `process.argv`.

Is there a flag I should be providing when I build the app that allows for this behavior?

The Node.js page on process.argv was not very helpful.